# V-loop Passing Data in Vue Js

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, vuejs2, axios

I am using a v-for loop to loop over a record of students doing a particular subject. I need to assign each students marks for exams sat for. I am finding it difficult to type unique mark in the text fields as they get repeated in all fields with similar v-model. How do i go about it?

```
    <div id="">   
                            <tbody>
                         <tr v-for="item in subjectStudentsData">
                          <td>{{item.surname}}</td>
                          <td>{{item.registrationNumber}}</td>
                          <td>
                              <input type="text" v-model="exam.cat1" />
                          </td>
                              <td>
                              <input type="text" v-model="exam.cat2" />
                          </td>
                              <td>
                              <input type="text" v-model="exam.cat3" />
                          </td>
                              <td>
                              <input type="text" v-model="exam.mainExam" />
                          </td>
                          <td>
                              <input type="button" value="Save" />
                          </td>
                          </tr>
                   </tbody>
                   </table>                        

    </div>

   my script section                                
    <script type="text/javascript">

          var subjectStudentsVM=new Vue({
          el:"#subjectStudentsSection",
          data:function(){  
                   return {
                           subjectStudentsData:[

                               {
                                 surname:"Simon",
                                 registrationNumber:"20",
                                 subjects:{
                                            id:"2"
                                          name:"English"
                                           }
                                },
                                {
                                  surname:"Kuch",
                                  registrationNumber:"23",
                                  subjects:{
                                             id:"2"
                                           name:"English"
                                            }
                                 },
                                   ],
                                 exam:{
                                             cat1:'',
                                             cat2:'',
                                             cat3:'',
                                         mainExam:''
                                       }
                            }   
                           }

                        })


                        </script>
```

Comment: I don't believe `subjectStudentsData[{"Simon"},{"John"}]` is syntactically valid. I'm guessing your template should say something like `v-model="item.value"` instead of `v-model:value="item"` but it's difficult to tell exactly which field you're trying to target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to have an `exam` a property on each student:

```js
subjectStudentsData: [
  {
    surname: "Simon",
    registrationNumber: "20",
    subjects: {
      id: "2"
      name: "English"
    },
    exam: {
      cat1: '',
      cat2: '',
      cat3: '',
      mainExam: ''
    }
  },
  {
    surname: "Kuch",
    registrationNumber: "23",
    subjects: {
      id: "2"
      name: "English"
    },
    exam: {
      cat1: '',
      cat2: '',
      cat3: '',
      mainExam: ''
    }
  },
]
```

Within your template you can then refer to the appropriate `exam` object:

```html
<input type="text" v-model="item.exam.cat1" />
```

Potentially there is a problem with this approach if you're unable to add the `exam` property to each `item`. For example, that might be because the `subjectStudentsData` objects are used elsewhere so you don't want to mutate them. It could also be a violation of one-way data flow if they're coming from the parent component or store.

If that's the case you have two alternatives:

1. Create a separate object or array to hold the exam objects. You still need one exam object per student. If you use an array then you would pair them up by array index. If you use an object then you can use some form of id to perform the mapping. Either way you'll need to be careful to keep the two in sync and the usual Vue reactivity caveats will likely also apply.
2. Wrap the objects as a pair in another object. In this approach you create a wrapper object that holds the student and the exam. The student isn't mutated but the template does need to be updated to handle the new format. Keeping the new array in sync is also a problem with this approach.

For this second alternative the data ends up looking something like this:

```js
subjectStudentsData: [
  {
    student: {
      surname: "Simon",
      registrationNumber: "20",
      subjects: {
        id: "2"
        name: "English"
      }
    },
    exam: {
      cat1: '',
      cat2: '',
      cat3: '',
      mainExam: ''
    }
  },
  {
    student: {
      surname: "Kuch",
      registrationNumber: "23",
      subjects: {
        id: "2"
        name: "English"
      }
    },
    exam: {
      cat1: '',
      cat2: '',
      cat3: '',
      mainExam: ''
    }
  },
]
```

The template would then need updating accordingly to use these nested paths. The key thing to note here is that the original objects holding the student data haven't been changed. They are stored in the `student` property of the wrapper objects. The `exam` objects have then been stored in the `exam` property of the wrapper object.

I would stress that the sample above just shows the *shape* of the data. In practice the `student` property will be coming from elsewhere, it wouldn't be inline like it appears in the example.

A further alternative would be to introduce a new component to represent the rows. Each row would have its own local `data` properties available, naturally leading to each one having its own `exam` object. Whether this is a good solution for your use case depends a little on what needs access to the `exam` object and whether you can cleanly pass around the relevant objects to where they're needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to bind each input with a `v-model` then you need to provide the data properties for that. 
Your code might look like this:

```
<tr v-for="(item, index) in subjectStudentsData">
...
<input type="text" v-model="subjectStudentsData[index]"/>
...
data(){    
  return {
    subjectStudentsData: [{"Simon"},{"John"}], //note the syntax 
          }   
       },
```

Now you could go about it in a few other things like use a function inside the loop but this does work.